# WorksheetFunction.Vlookup and Run-time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I'm keep running into a error when trying to use worksheetfunction.Vlookup. The error is given as:

> Run-Time Error 1004 (Application-defined or object-defined error)

The error occurs in the code for "g". My code is:

```
Sub Rankings()

Dim f As Variant
Dim n As Variant
Dim h As Variant
Dim e As Integer
Dim d As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim g As Variant

d = 2
e = 2

While d < 7

    c = 2
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    While Cells(c, 1) <> vbNullString
        n = Right(Cells(c, 1), Len(Cells(c, 1)) - 1)
        h = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, e).End(xlUp).Row
        g = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(n, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3, e - 1), Cells(h, e)), 2, False)
        f = WorksheetFunction.Rank_Eq(g, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3, e), Cells(h, e)), 1)
        If Not IsError(f) Then
            Cells(c, d) = f
        Else
            Cells(c, d) = WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3, e), Cells(h, e)) + 1)
        End If

    Wend
Wend

End Sub
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to rank the values in sheet 2, column 2, and put them into the cells in column 2 in sheet 1, corresponding to the relevant golfer.

Any suggestions on how to fix the error?

[image: Sheet2 information]
[image: Sheet1 information]

Comment: `c` is not incremented?

Comment: c, d, and e will increment by different amounts. However, the error occurs in the current situation, and I was looking to test the code in the first instance before working on the incrementation elements.

Comment: @ScottCraner Vlookup is NOT case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common error. Having activated Sheet1, you attempt to perform a vlookup in a range located on Sheet2.

`g = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(n, Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(3, e - 1), Cells(h, e)), 2, False)`

**HOWEVER**, your Range that you construct as a parameter to the Vlookup is using a Cells call to the ***active sheet(Sheet1).***

It is advisable to get handles to your worksheets when switching between sheets often, like so:

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
```

then you should do like:

```
g = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(n, ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(3, e - 1), ws2.Cells(h, e)), 2, False)
```